# How to specify dtype when using pandas.read_csv to load data from csv files?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some text files with the following format:

```
000423|东阿阿胶|     300|1|0.15000|            |
000425|徐工机械|     600|1|0.15000|            |
000503|海虹控股|     400|1|0.15000|            |
000522|白云山Ａ|        |2|       |    1982.080|
000527|美的电器|     900|1|0.15000|            |
000528|柳    工|     300|1|0.15000|            |
```

---

when I use read_csv to load them into DataFrame, it doesn't generate correct dtype for some columns. For example, the first column is parsed as int, not unicode str, the third column is parsed as unicode str, not int, because of one missing data... Is there a way to preset the dtype of the DataFrame, just like the numpy.genfromtxt does?

Updates:
I used `read_csv` like this which caused the problem:

```
data = pandas.read_csv(StringIO(etf_info), sep='|', skiprows=14, index_col=0, 
                       skip_footer=1, names=['ticker', 'name', 'vol', 'sign', 
                       'ratio', 'cash', 'price'], encoding='gbk')
```

In order to solve both the dtype and encoding problems, I need to use `unicode()` and `numpy.genfromtxt` first:

```
etf_info = unicode(urllib2.urlopen(etf_url).read(), 'gbk')
nd_data = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(etf_info), delimiter='|', 
                        skiprows=14, skip_footer=1, dtype=ETF_DTYPE)
data = pandas.DataFrame(nd_data, index=nd_data['ticker'],
                        columns=['name', 'vol', 'sign', 
                                 'ratio', 'cash', 'price'])
```

It would be nice if `read_csv` can add `dtype` and `usecols` settings. Sorry for my greed. ^_^

Comment: Indeed, some more work is needed on the file readers. See here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/926. Hopefully a magical developer will come out of the woodwork and help me out with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put: no, not yet. More work (read: more active developers) is needed on this particular area. If you could post how you're using `read_csv` it might help. I suspect that the whitespace between the bars may be the problem

EDIT: this is now obsolete. This behavior is covered natively by [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Thanks Wes. Just watched your PyCon video on Data analysis in Python with pandas from youtube. Great help!

Answer (score 1):

You can now use dtype in [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

PS: Kudos to [Wes McKinney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792865/how-to-specify-the-dtype-of-index-when-read-a-csv-file-to-dataframe) for answering, it feels quite awkward to contradict the "past Wes".