# How to specify the `dtype` of index when read a csv file to `DataFrame`?

Tags: python, pandas

In python 3.4.3 and Pandas 0.16, how to specify the `dtype` of index as `str`?
The following code is what I have tried:

```
In [1]: from io import StringIO

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: fra = pd.read_csv(StringIO('date,close\n20140101,10.2\n20140102,10.5'), index_col=0, dtype={'date': np.str_, 'close': np.float})

In [5]: fra.index
Out[5]: Int64Index([20140101, 20140102], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like the param `index_col=0` is taking precedence over the `dtype` param, if you drop the `index_col` param then you can call `set_index` after:

```
In [235]:

fra = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('date,close\n20140101,10.2\n20140102,10.5'), dtype={'date': np.str_, 'close': np.float})
fra
Out[235]:
       date  close
0  20140101   10.2
1  20140102   10.5
In [236]:

fra = fra.set_index('date')
fra.index
Out[236]:
Index(['20140101', '20140102'], dtype='object')
```

An alternative is to drop the `index_col` param and just call `set_index` on the df returned from `read_csv` so it becomes a one-liner:

```
In [237]:

fra = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('date,close\n20140101,10.2\n20140102,10.5'), dtype={'date': np.str_, 'close': np.float}).set_index('date')
fra.index
Out[237]:
Index(['20140101', '20140102'], dtype='object')
```

**Update**

This is a [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9435) which is targeted for version `0.17.0`

Comment: This bug was not fixed in 0.17

Comment: @Eastsun Can you comment on the issue so that it pings the devs, thanks it may have slipped their attention

Comment: Nor was it fixed in 0.18

Comment: Nor was it fixed in 1.1.3

Comment: Finally fixed and scheduled to be released in v1.4.0: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/44632/files